# Adjusted risk plot

Tags: r, plot, spss, survival-analysis, risk-analysis

With the following dataframe:

```
death <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
age<-c (70,50,60,60,55,46,50,60,59,61,62,55,66,60,59,58,61,59,58,60,60,58,60,60,61,61,59,60,61,64)
survival_time <- c(4,29,24,29,29,29,29,19,29,29,29,3,9,29,15,29,29,11,29,5,13,20,22,29,16,21,9,29,29,15)
diabetes <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
bloodpressure <- c(160,120,150,140,135,110,139,140,153,129,149,163,179,129,144,119,100,115,145,150,130,120,122,129,116,171,129,126,159,150)
data <- data.frame(death, survival_time, diabetes, bloodpressure,age)
```

I'd like to create a plot similar to the following one:
[image]

The variables I got are blood pressure, Cardiovascular mortality, survival_time, Diabetes, age. I'd like to adjust for age and Diabetes.

Is there a way to do this in R or SPSS?

My first try does not deliver the result I was hoping for:

```
cfit4a <- coxph(Surv(survival_time, death) ~ age + diabetes + bloodpressure, data=data) 
surv4a <- survfit(cfit4a) 
plot(surv4a, col=c(1,2,4), mark.time=F, xscale=365.25, xlab="blood pressure", ylab="Survival")
```

How can I create a plot which displays the blood pressure values on the x axis? How can I display Adjusted risk instead of survival at the y axis? (I added a sample data in the original post above)

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/adjcurve.pdf

Comment: @BenBolker 
I tried the following code which unfortunately doesn't deliver the result I was hoping for: 
`cfit4a <- coxph(Surv(survival_time, death) ~ age + diabetes + bloodpressure,
                data=data)

surv4a <- survfit(cfit4a)

plot(surv4a, col=c(1,2,4), mark.time=F, xscale=365.25,
     xlab="blood pressure", ylab="Survival")`


How can I create a plot which displays the blood pressure values on the x axis?
How can I display Adjusted risk instead of survival at the y axis?
(I added a sample data in the original post above)

Comment: You can edit your question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a plot of the adjusted relative risk for blood pressure in the context of a multivariate model that includes not only blood pressure but age (as numeric) and diabetes (as a 1/0 indicator). A simple approach is to use `predict.coxph` with a type of "risk" and submit a dataframe with blood pressure given as a range of values with `age` and `diabetes` set at some specified level. For this prediction it  matters what the specified levels are because the reference values for `age` and `diabetes` will affect the relative risk estimates. I believe that Therneau uses the mean values of covariates to set the baseline hazard. So instead of picking a particualr value for those covariates you could have used `mean(data$age)` and `mean(data$diabetes)` which should have forced the value of `bloodpressure`'s RR to be 1 at the mean of `bloodpressure`.

```
bp.df <- data.frame(bloodpressure=seq(120,210,by=5), age=60, diabetes=0)
pred.rr.bp <- predict(cfit4a, newdata=bp.df,type="risk", se.fit=TRUE)

plot( x = bp.df$bloodpressure, y=pred.rr.bp$fit, type="l", ylim=c(0,10), main="BP Relative Risk with age=60 and diabetes=0")
lines(x = bp.df$bloodpressure, 
          y=pred.rr.bp$fit+1.96*pred.rr.bp$se.fit,lty=3)
lines(x = bp.df$bloodpressure, 
          y=pred.rr.bp$fit-1.96*pred.rr.bp$se.fit,lty=3)
```

[image]

The `rms`-pkg could also be used. It requires some extra study to master its special requirements, but if you really need the std-error lines to meet at the median bp as your example demonstrates, then it's plotting routines do provide that "feature". I've always been a bit bothered by it, however, the exact values of the +/-1.96*s.e.-lines are really not that important.